# How to have a variable in the current tab for my Firefox extension?

Tags: firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm developing my first Firefox extension and I'm a beginner.
I have a script in background that intercepts the event onBeforeRequest.
I would like to store a temporary variable on a tab, especially to see if I have already run my script on the current tab.
my variable is not persistent.

Example but doesn't work.

```
browser.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
   (request) => {
        if(browser.tabs.getCurrent().myvar != true ){
                execMyScript(request);
                browser.tabs.getCurrent().myvar = true;
        }
   }, {urls: ['http://*/*']},["blocking"]
 );
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may save the variable on the background itself.

```
 let tabsVisited = {};
 browser.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
   (request) => {
        if(!(request.tabId in tabsVisited)){
                execMyScript(request);
                tabsVisited[request.tabId] = true;
        }
   }, {urls: ['http://*/*']},["blocking"]
 );
```

but `tabsVisited` will only grow larger. you need to find a spot in your script to `delete tabsVisited[request.tabId]` when you are done. maybe when the user closes the tab.